# How to activate sound alarms for the Katwarn app?

Tags: windows-10-mobile, apps, settings

How do I activate sound alarms for the Katwarn app? At the moment the app only shows notifications, which you will miss if you don't check your phone regularly.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is not supported by the application? I think your best bet is contacting the developers/company that create the application.
If you don't find the settings in your Windows Phone, then it is maybe not supported in the app.